# How do I get xpath for id

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to learn xpath and CSSselector. 
Go to https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/create-account.jspx
and I am trying to find xpath for email. How do I find css by ID for email. With name I can find, but How about with ID.

So can you help me what will be css with ID for email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the css for the email.

```
#email\:\:content
```

basically you have to use the escape for the `:`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tagname with id

```
input#email\:\:content
```